# Django: How to deploy static files on an apache server in production

Tags: django, apache, production

Static files are not loading in production of my Django project. I am using mod-wsgi to serve the static files.

Static files were serving fine in development (when DEBUG=True), but now I get 404 errors when the static files are trying to be called.

My file structure is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVYHo.jpg

/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <ip address>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/var/www/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/mysite/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/mysite/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static/
    Alias /media/ /var/www/mysite/media/

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/mysite/static_root/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/mysite/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

ol' reliable: DigitalOcean

[how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Apache should be looking at your STATIC_ROOT directory, after you've run `collectstatic`.

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite/static_root>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: `Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static/` might also need to be changed to `Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static_root/`

Comment: @Omar i made this change too and its still throwing errors :(

Comment: thank you for sharing this, unfortunately it hasn't solved the issues.i still get the following error: ... "GET /static/base/css/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 77... i tried to fix it further by taking out the trailing "/" in both Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static/
    Alias /media/ /var/www/mysite/media/  @Daniel Roseman